# UIView.animateWithDuration swift loop animation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-animation, uiviewanimation

In ViewController.Swift I managed to make a box animate from one point to another. I thought it would be easy to loop this so the box will animate to one point and then animate back to its original position and then loop again. I have managed to move the object to a position and in "complete" move it back again, but that doesn't make i loop. How can this be achieved?

I thought maybe this could work but i honestly don't know:

```
let boxmoves = [CGRect(x: 120, y: 220, width: 100, height: 100), CGRect(x: 120, y: 120, width: 100, height: 100)]
for boxmove in boxmoves {
    coloredSquare.frame = boxmove
}
```

How could I center it based on the device-width (I assume there are some math involved?)?

My code:

```
let coloredSquare = UIView()

coloredSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 120, width: 100, height: 100)

self.view.addSubview(coloredSquare)

// found repeate but this will not animate as I want.
//UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: {
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {

    coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 220, width: 100, height: 100)

    }, completion: { finished in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
        coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 120, width: 100, height: 100)
        })
})
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

No need to do the completion block approach, just use the animation options argument:

*updated for Swift 3.0*

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {

    coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 220, width: 100, height: 100)

}, completion: nil)
```

If for any reason you want to stop the animation later, just use:

```
coloredSquare.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Comment: Wow, it was that easy. Thanks @Mazyod! Do you know how to center it based on device-width as well?

Comment: @JohanNdiyoLinnarsson Well, you'd have to remove all those hard coded values, obviously. Try setting the frame with the size you want, then animating the `coloredSquare.center` property, instead of the frame. To center it in the view, try `coloredSquare.center = view.center`, or better `coloredSquare.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)`

Comment: if you're not using autolayout, you'd also need to set the `autoresizingMask` property to flexible margins.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help @Mazyod. With your help I manage to solve my problem.

Comment: @Blankarsch `coloredSquare.layer.removeAllAnimations()`

Comment: For a UIButton animation: use buttonName.imageView?.layer.removeAllAnimations()

Answer (score 2):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0,
                           delay: 0.0,
                           options: [.curveLinear, .repeat],
                           animations: { () -> Void in
                           coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 220, width: 100, height: 100)

}, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

})
```