# Animated width label with swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to change the width of my label since my swift code.
If possible, do it in a annimation prograssif for a change. Is it possible ?
When I do:

```
self.lblChoice1.frame.size.width += 50
```

My exchange label width not ... Why?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :**
The first response is not working.

```
print(self.lblChoice1.frame.size.width)
self.lblChoice1.frame.size.width += 150
self.lblChoice1.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw
self.lblChoice1.setNeedsDisplay()
print(self.lblChoice1.frame.size.width)
```

This code displays me well in my console:

```
150.0
300.0
```

But my label size does not change the display ...

Comment: Why do you think the code you posted should animate the change?

Comment: No, but it should change the width of my label ...

Comment: @hugo_082 From what I see you should start with some tutorials to learn about this animation first: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76200/basic-uiview-animation-swift-tutorial or you could take a look at this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660540/uiview-animatewithduration-swift-loop-animation

Comment: I've already read the tutorial is, and I understand that. But I understand why the line of code I posted above you does not change the width of my label?

Comment: UI-related tasks should always be done on the main queue, so if you are calling that line above from a different context/queue it won't work

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the frame, but you aren't telling the view that it needs to redraw itself.  After changing the frame you should then call

```
self.lblchoice1.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Although you may need to change the label's content mode to `UIViewContentModeRedraw` to make sure it redraws.

Although it would be better to use UIView block animation methods to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can edit the UILabel's frame directly. You should change entire frame instead.

```
var lblChoice1Frame = self.lblChoice1.frame
lblChoice1Frame.size.width += 150

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
    self.lblChoice1.frame =  lblChoice1Frame
}
```

Comment: This does not change the initial size of my label. It just creating a progressive display annimation my label ...