# stop animateWithDuration in navigationItem

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationitem

i am trying to animate my `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` to blink repeatedly from green to white... So I do this

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay:0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .greenColor()                
}, completion: nil)
```

as i see in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660540/uiview-animatewithduration-swift-loop-animation)

and it work

the problem is that i am using `UITabView` and every time i switch between views and return to the first view the blink is stop

and i think its because i stuck layer after layer of animation somewhere

i understand that to remove the animation i should use `layer.removeAllAnimations()`

the problem is that i don't know which view to do it on

i tried `self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()`
and it didn't work.

how do i get to this layer that i create for the navigationItem animation

so i can remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this issue with relocating the creation of the animation

in the beginning i placed that in the viewWillAppear function

and also tried to init the button to white color just before that

but its looks like it didn't work that way so i relocate the animation to

the viewDidAppear function and leave the init of the button to white color

in the viewWillAppear and its seems to work ok now :)

thanks